# Simple eigenvectors help

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I do not understand how to compute this eigenvector

$   \begin{pmatrix} -c & -2c \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{pmatrix} $

eigenvalues are -c and 1/2

but I don't get how to compute the eigenvectors. 
for examplw for the eigenvalue 1/2

$   \begin{pmatrix} -c  -\frac{1}{2} & -2c \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} $ $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ =

the equation i get is $ (-c-\frac{1}{2} ) x = 2 c y$

and for the eigenvalue = -c am not sure how to compute this either.

Comment: Well, there isn't one eigenvector, but a vector space of eigenvectors, so what you're getting is completely correct and if you want an example of eigenvectors, just substitute $x$ or $y$ with whatever value you want and deduce the other coordinate from the formula you found, so in your case $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -\frac{c+\frac{1}{2}}{2c} \end{pmatrix}$ For the other eigenvector, just do the same thing you did first.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif the special case of $c=0$ needs to be treated separately, where $(0,1)^T$ is an Eigenvector.

Comment: but the correct answer is $ \begin {pmarix} 2c \\ -(c+ 1/2) \end{pmatrix} $ and (1,0)

Comment: @Roland Of course

Comment: @italy which is Oussama's vector, multiplied with 2c.

Comment: @italy Remember that if a vector is an eigenvector, then a non zero constant times that vector is also an eigenvector. What happens when you multiply the last answer by, say, $2c$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll continue your calculation for the first eigenvector:
$$ (-c-\frac{1}{2}) x = 2cy$$
$$ x = -\frac{2c}{c+\frac12} y $$
Meaning that the eigenvectors have the following form:
$$\left \{ \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{2c}{c+\frac12} y \\ y \end{pmatrix} | y \in \mathbb{R} \right \} = \operatorname{span} \left \{ \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{2c}{c+\frac12}  \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right \} $$

Now I hope you know how to proceed to the second eigenvector :)

Comment: In your notation, $c=-0.5$ needs to be treated separately.

Comment: You're correct, in that case we have a Jordan matrix and so there is only one eigenvector

Comment: The form of the matrix doesn't matter: It's the fact that $0=-y$ can only satisfied by $y=0\neq 1$

Comment: Of course, I just gave a reason not to be surprised when he'll find only one eigenvector

Comment: I dont see how any of  these answers is the same as the vector $ (  2c, -(c+1/2)  )^{T} $

Comment: Multiply the vector by the scalar $-(c+\frac12)$